# Update page layout sidebar-main and column.main widths

Tags: magento2, layout, css

I'm on Magento 2.2.4 and I can't figure out how to edit the CSS for the catalog view page. I'm trying to edit

```
.page-layout-2columns-left .column.main
```

and

```
.page-layout-2columns-left .sidebar-additional
```

so that it's the same width as the layout when you login as a customer.

Sidebars being 22.3% and main content being 77.7%.

I tried adding this code to overwrite in my /Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.css but the **column.main** style is still reading 83.333333% somewhere.

```
.page-layout-2columns-left {
    .column.main {
        width: 77.7%;
    }

    .sidebar-additional,
    .sidebar-main {
        width: 22.3%;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can also add custom css and add your custom styles there.

Comment: @Pawan yes, the code above is the CSS I put but like I said, the column.main is not reading it's width. It's still using the width of 83.333333% somewhere and I'm not sure where. So I was wondering if someone can help with that.

Comment: I mean custom css in separate custom CSS file.

Comment: @Pawan ah okies. Interesting, it worked once I moved it to a different css file. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @Amy, Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom CSS by creating `default_head_blocks.xml` at :

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/layout

With following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
     <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css" />
     </head>
</page>
```

Location of `custom.css` will be

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/web/css/custom.css

Hope above will help

If found suitable, Please accept and Up vote:)